# First I want to convert array to Arraylist or any collection and to get the max size from that collection

Tags: java

```
static int  hurdleRace(int k, int[] height) { 
    List list = Arrays.asList((height));  
    Integer max=Collections.max(list);
}
```

```
Solution.java:17: error: incompatible types
    Integer max=Collections.max(list);
                                   ^
required: Integer
found:    Object
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to do in the body of your Question.

Comment: Integer[] height = {1,3,5,16,7,8};
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(height);
        Integer max= Collections.max(list);

Answer (score 2):

First you can not use `Collections.max` for List of Object and here `Arrays.asList` convert int array into `List<int[]>`  not `List<int>`

You can use `Arrays.stream` and `max()` to get max value

```
int max = Arrays.stream(height).max().getAsInt();
```

You can first convert into a list

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(height).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then get max

```
  Integer max= Collections.max(list);
```

Comment: Super but after converting array to List i want to take max value from that list

Comment: yeah i got the max value super